# Contact-Form 7 reloads page instead of doing AJAX

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am having my first go at converting a **HTML** template to a custom **WP theme**, so far everything is working out quite well and it's a very nice learning process..

I am using Advanced Custom Fields with Advanced Custom Fields: **Contact Form 7** plugin. And set it to display in the following way:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="135" title="contactform"]' ); ?>
```

Everything is displaying the way it should, however when I press submit (if filled) it seems to reload the page while adding the following to the URL:

```
 /?_wpcf7=135&_wpcf7_version=5.1.6&_wpcf7_locale=da_DK&_wpcf7_unit_tag=wpcf7-f135-o1&_wpcf7_container_post=0&your-name&your-email&your-phone
```

If it's not filled it just reloads the page.

This indicates that something doesn't work the way it should, since CF7 normally comes with error (if not filled) or a success message (if filled).

Hope someone can figure this one out.

**UPDATE**

I managed to it from reloading, the reason was that the php statement was wrapped in

`<form></form>`

However now it doesn't submit, I am only left with a loading icon which turns around. I looked into what the error might be and got the following:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yb6bB.png)

**UPDATE - PROBLEM IS MAYBE FIXED**

So after looking up solutions I found out that having permalinks settings on postname instead of normal caused the error. I am running a local install however I am not sure how it will react when it comes lives. Anyone who has a solution or knows whats causing this?